# How to pass multiple parameters to WebAPI Action using HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Web API action as following:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<FavoriteDTO> GetFavoritesPaged(long userId, PagingInfo pagingInfo)
{
  var result = _userService.GetFavoritesPaged(fav => fav.UserId == userId, pagingInfo);
  var favDTOs = ConvertToDTOs(result.Source);
  return favDTOs;
}
```

I need to call it using HttpClient and I am trying it as following:

paging info needs to be passed to the get method.

```
var pagingInfo = new PagingInfo()
{
    PageIndex = 1,
    PageSize = 10,
    OrderBy = "URL",
    OrderDirection = OrderDirection.Desc
};
```

where OrderDirection is an enum:

```
public enum OrderDirection
  {
    Asc,
    Desc
  }

var detailURI = "Favorites/GetFavoritesPaged?userId="+34;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
client.BaseAddress="mywebApiAddress";
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(detailURI, pagingInfo).Result;
response.EnsureSuccessCode();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result,
                                      tyepof(FavoritesDTO));
```

But, its not working. It says internal server error, what I am missing here; is the enum causing problem or something else? I have other WebAPIs working just fine; none of them has more than one parameter like this.

Here is my routConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
```

Is it the right way to call the WebAPI with multiple parameters or is there a better way, please suggest?

**EDIT-1:**
changed this:

```
 var detailURI = "Favorites/GetFavoritesPaged?userId?"+34;
```

to:

```
var detailURI = "Favorites/GetFavoritesPaged?userId="+34;
```

All it was a typo :)

**EDIT-2:**

With EDIT-1 the request goes to follwing WebAPI method (which is wrong):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public FavoriteDTO AddToFavorites(FavoriteDTO favoriteDTO)
    {
      ------code to add to db------
    }
```

But, when I edited the routeConfig to the following:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```

Then I started getting the following exception:

```
ReasonPhrase: Not Found
Request: {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:60208/api/Favorite/GetPagedFavorites?user=1', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Headers:{  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  Content-Length: 44}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try putting an ActionName attribute on the controller method. Then append the ActionName to your query string.

/ActionName?param=value

Answer (score 1):

Your url is wrong. Try like this:

```
var detailURI = "Favorites/GetFavoritesPaged?userId=34";
```

or use the `{id}` route:

```
var detailURI = "Favorites/GetFavoritesPaged/34";
```

But you're gonna have to modify your parameter name:

```
public List<FavoriteDTO> GetFavoritesPaged(long id, PagingInfo pagingInfo)
```

Comment: just updated my question as you pointed out. And its working. But, is there a better way that you can think of; instead of doing this (adding params in url).

Comment: There's nothing wrong in passing the Id parameter in the url. Another possibility is to use a view model and put everything in the POST body payload and then have your action take a single parameter which will represent your view model.

Comment: Actualy, it is still not working. It goes to another method which also has a POST verb attribute and a single parameter. [I was wrong initially when I said its working, since I didn't notice its going somewhere else]. When I change the route config (see the edit) it says "Not Found". Please see edit for more detail of exception.

Comment: your Edit-2's uri seems to be having a typo "api/Favorite/"...should it be "api/Favorites" ?

Comment: @Kiran, Actually, I have renamed my controller from "FavoritesController" to "FavoriteController", thats why you see that. Any other clues?

Comment: Can you give us the information of what the exception details look like over the wire?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to post an anonymous type, and have the Controller accept a dynamic.

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(new { detailURI, pagingInfo }).Result;

[HttpPost]
public List<FavoriteDTO> GetFavoritesPaged([FromBody]dynamic model)
{
    PagingInfo pagingInfo = (PagingInfo)model.pagingInfo;
    long userid = (long)model.userId;

    ...

}
```